# Spring.addElementDecoration for dijit.form.filteringselect fails in IE

Tags: spring, dojo, spring-roo

I am using Spring Roo to create a page that makes ajax call and populates a section of the page with the search form from the Ajax call. This is all done by using standard Roo tags and Javascript libraries. The form that is returned by Ajax is simple, just one select list.

```
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields"
xmlns:form="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form"
xmlns:springform="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" 
xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
<div>
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <form:search
        id="fc_domain_profile_combination"
        modelAttribute="combination" path="/profiles/search/combinations"
        z="e2lXrqKKD2CS7Zjefas2ZXPW4xYNM=">
        <field:select field="searchProcessingCenter" renderempty="true" disabled="true"
                id="c_profile_combofilter_processingcenter"
                items="${proccenters}" path="/profiles"
                itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
    </form:search>
    <input type="hidden" id="blockSubmitHd" value="false" />
</div>
```

This code works fine in Firefox and Google Chrome but fails in IE with "Unknown error". The problem is happens in the Ajax method included in Roo:

```
function callXhrGet(contentId, ajaxUrl){
  var _targetNode = dojo.byId(contentId);
  var xhrArgs = {
      url: ajaxUrl,
      preventCache: true,
      handleAs:"text",
      load: function(data) {
        dojo.html.set(_targetNode,data,{parseContent:true});
        dojo.forEach(dojo.query("script", _targetNode),function(node){
            dojo.eval(node.innerHTML);
        });
        dojo.parser.parse(_targetNode);
      },
      error: function(error) {
          _targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
      }
  };
  dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
```

}

The `dojo.eval(node.innerHTML);` fails when tries to process following line:

```
Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : '_searchProcessingCenter_id', widgetType: 'dijit.form.FilteringSelect', widgetAttrs : {hasDownArrow : true, required : false, invalidMessage: 'Please enter valid Role Type' }}));
```

The interesting part is that when the list is empty it works fine, other `dijit.form.tags` work fine as well. Any advice and feedback how to resolve this issue?